# What is the serve:ssr script for, if the browser displays html in the source code anyway? I just made a project with ng new --ssr

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, vercel, angular16, angular17

What is the `serve:ssr` script for, if the browser shows html in the source code? When I didn't use ssr in Angular 16 it didn't show it, now it shows it, shows it even when I fetch data via the API, although I didn't do any additional configuration, except that I created a project with `ng new --ssr`. Is my deployment e.g. on Vercel changes with ssr introduced in Angular 17?

I tried to transfer the whole project to Angular 17 from Angular 16 and use ssr, which I didn't use in Angular 16. Now I want to deploy, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something, is ssr really implemented on the updated version?

Comment: When server-side-rendering is used, the server will return the pre-rendered HTML.  So the difference you'll see in the browser would be the difference between right-clicking on the page and choosing, "View Page Source", as opposed to "Inspect".  The Inspector shows you the DOM (the current Document Object Model).  Page Source is the initial HTML/page served up.  When SSR is on, you'll see no difference between Page Source and DOM.  When SSR is off there will be a big difference because client-side JS will render the components.  (Page Source won't change, DOM will.)